# Visual Basic, How to exit sub when user checks Cancel button in modal form?

Tags: vb.net

I have a sub that opens a modal form that lets the user checks an item off of a listbox. There are two buttons on the modal form, OK and Cancel. when OK is checked, the code is just Me.Hide(). The modal form is hidden and the the sub continues.

However, I'm not sure what the code for the cancel button would be like. I do not want the form hiding or closing, because the sub will just continue. I can see an if statement:

```
Dim intResult = form.ShowDialog
If intResult = DialogResult.Cancel Then
Exit Sub
End If
```

But I don't see a way how I can access the clicked property of the Cancel button from this form or access the clicked event.

Answer (score 2):

Buttons have a property named `DialogResult`. Set it to the value you want to be reported back from the `ShowDialog` method of your form.

Any value but `DialogResult.None` have the effect to close your form (no Hide needed, no event handler needed). The value of the [DialogResult property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) of the button becomes the return value of `ShowDialog()`